# How to change swagger response for exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, exceptionmapper

I am using spring boot with swagger for REST API services. The swagger returns the response in the following format when exception occurs

```
    {
  "timestamp": 1449742584285,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "com.foo.exception.NotFoundException",
  "message": "User with id 1 not found",
  "path": "/user/1"
}
```

Instead of returning the detailed response I want to show only the message. Also all the time the server tkhrows an `RuntimeException`.

How to achieve swagger to retun only the message.

Comment: Are you saying this is what your Swagger documentation is is displaying? Swagger should have nothing to do with the error being returned

Comment: I want to configure the swagger response. I am expecting only message as response by excluding timestamp, error, exception and path information

Comment: @Leon Any suggestions..